# Why doesn't IP checksum only checks for corruption in the IP header and not in the whole datagram?

Tags: networking

So, IP checksum only checks for corruption or problems in IP Header, Why does it not check for the entire datagram, and does fragmentation influence this in any way ?

Comment: Because UDP and TCP have their own checksums.

Comment: That is only true for IPv4. IP also means IPv6, which has eliminated the checksum in order to speed packet forwarding. That works because the network layers above and below the IP packets have error detection. For example, ethernet has the FCS that covers the entire frame, including the IP packet payload.

Answer (score 1):

from [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791):

> There are some applications where a few data bit errors are acceptable while retransmission delays are not.  If the internet protocol enforced data correctness such applications could not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

To provide another way of thinking, since you have questions about the fields in ipv4, you can look at how to solve the problem in ipv6:
Does the field still exist?
Or has something changed?

If you observe the header of ipv6, you will find that there is no field indicating checksum.

why？According to wiki

> In order to increase performance, and since current link layer technology and transport layer protocols are assumed to provide sufficient error detection,[9] the header has no checksum to protect it.[1]